# ssh-keygen on snow leopard glitches in passwordless mode

Tags: osx-snow-leopard, ssh, passwords, openssh

I'm trying to use ssh-keygen to generate a key for a remote Linux server for passwordless entry.

Unfortunately, it doesn't want to work: I keep having to enter a password.

I'm wondering if there's some OS 10.6 configuration setting that interferes with this.

I'm not using ssh-agent or other similar tools

Answer (score 0):

Is the server setup properly for passwordless login. check /etc/ssh/sshd_config for

```
PubkeyAuthentication yes
```

Trying connecting with -v, -vv or -vvv

When you say keep having to enter the password, whats the exact message. It may be asking you to unlock the key to use it and if you don't have an agent it'll keep asking.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using a password on your key. You can use ssh-agent to avoid having to type the password so many times.

Answer (score 0):

The password your entering is actually the **passphrase** for your public key.

I posted with similar concerns not too long ago. read up.

[SSH Keys Still Prompts for Passphrase](https://superuser.com/questions/531869/ssh-keys-still-prompts-for-passphrase)