# SSH Keys Still Prompts for Passphrase

Tags: ssh

I recently generated ssh keys, copying my public key to the server I need access to and keeping my private key in my ~/.ssh/ directory.

Everything works great but ssh prompts me for the passphrase every single time I want to login to the server. I was under the impression that if I am logged in as root and have the private key stored locally in my directory, the passphrase is only needed at first login.

Ideally I would like to access the server seamlessely using no passphrase and just the key, this way I can passwordless rsync and such.

Is this possible? I do remember an option to include a passphrase and typed one in assuming this was most secure. Maybe I shouldn't have.

Comment: did you injected the public-key into `.ssh/authorized_keys` or did you just 'copied it into `.ssh`'?

Comment: I injected it into the authorized keys file.

Answer (score 1):

If your private key has a password on it and you only want to have to enter the password once per session, use ssh-agent and ssh-add.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, setting a new passphrase but leaving it blank was the solution. It appears you can cache the passphrase in a file for an extended period of time but I require seamless backups with zero worry.

**ssh-keygen -p**

Comment: "Setting a new passphrase but leaving it blank" is better known as "removing the passphrase."  Your could have also removed the passphrase from your existing key by [this method](https://knowledge.digicert.com/solution/SO5292.html).